# How to disable btrfs snapshots created by apt?

Tags: apt, btrfs

Is there a way to configure `apt` to prevent the creation of btrfs snapshots?

I know I can delete the snapshots generated by `apt install` by executing `apt-btrfs-snapshot delete-older-than 0d`, but what I want is to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to uninstall the package, even though i didn't tried it for myself and may imply other problems.

```
sudo apt-get remove apt-btrfs-snapshot
```

However: btrfs Snapshots do not use much diskspace per se, because its just taking track of the changes AFAIK

Comment: The snapshots start to fill up the disk soon, if you leave the partition like 40GB. With number of PCs, it gets to a situation when every few weeks one machine is stuck at full disk (root partition)

Comment: There is actually a chicken and egg problem: Just before apt-btrfs-snapshot is removed, it takes a snapshot. You then have to delete the snapshot yourself using `btrfs subvolume delete` (use `btrfs subvolume list /` to discover the name of the snapshot). fusilator's answer should be used whether you remove the package or not.

Answer (score 5):

you can disable the rule from apt.conf.d, it should be enough renaming the file with a suffix .disabled (apt only reads configuration files ending with .conf or without any extension)

```
$ cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/80-btrfs-snapshot
DPkg::Pre-Invoke {"if [ -x /usr/bin/apt-btrfs-snapshot ] && apt-btrfs-snapshot supported; then apt-btrfs-snapshot snapshot; fi "; };
```

you could then remove the scheduled job from /etc/cron.weekly
Anyway check your own package to see the installed files

```
dpkg -L apt-btrfs-snapshot
```